# arrayOutBoundsException

Tags: java, array

estoy haciendo un proyecto de clase y llevo horas mirando el codigo y no encuentro el fallo, le dejo el codigo y despues el fallo a ver si podeis encontrarlo, gracias de antemano:

```
public static String[][] peticionPalabras(){
    int orientacion;
    int arraySize=readInt("Dime la cantidad de palabras que desea añadir: ");
    String palabras[][]=new String [arraySize][4];
    //1.-Pedir datos al usuario
    //Paso primero por cada dato es decir del dato 1 guardamos ( Palabra, Fila, Columna y orientacion)
    for(int numDato=0; numDato< palabras.length;numDato++) { 
        //De este dato escogemos la informacion que quiera dar
        for(int infor=0;infor<palabras[numDato].length;infor++) {
            switch(infor) {
                //1.1.- Pedir palabra
                case 0:
                    do {
                        palabras[numDato][infor]=readString("Dame una palabra: ");
                    //2.- Comprobar que cumple los requisitos validos
                    }while(!palabras[numDato][infor].matches("[A-ZÑ]([a-zñ]{1,})([A-ZÑ]{1,2}[a-zñ]{1,})*"));//Solo acepta palabras que empiezen por mayusculas contengan minusculas,como mucho una o dos mayusculas y siga con minusculas
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //1.2.- Pedir fila
                    int fila;
                    while((fila=readInt("Dame una fila: "))<=0){//comprueba que no escriba 0
                        System.out.printf("La fila debe ser superior a 0\n\n");
                    }
                    palabras[numDato][infor]=String.valueOf(fila-1);//Se le resta 1 porque el usuario no te va a dar la 0 te dara de la 1 a la que sea
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //1.3.- Pedir columna
                    int columna;
                    while((columna=readInt("Dame una columna: "))<=0){//comprueba que no escriba 0
                        System.out.printf("La columna debe ser superior a 0\n\n");
                    }
                    palabras[numDato][infor]=String.valueOf(columna-1);//Se le resta 1 porque el usuario no te va a dar la 0 te dara de la 1 a la que sea
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //1.4.- Pedir orientacion
                    System.out.printf("Dame una orientacion: \n\t 1) En diagonal para Arriba hacia Izquierda\n\t 2) En diagonal para Arriba hacia Derecha\n\t"
                            + " 3) En diagonal para Abajo hacia Izquierda\n\t 4) En diagonal para Abajo hacia Derecha\n\t "
                            + "5) Para Arriba\n\t 6) Para Abajo\n\t 7) Para Derecha\n\t 8) Para Izquierda\n");
                    orientacion=between(BetweenOptions.BOTHIN,1,8); //Obliga a dar una orientacion entre las opciones.
                    palabras[numDato][infor]=String.valueOf(orientacion);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    //Devolver valor
    return palabras;

}

public static char [][] crearSopaLetras (String[][] palabras){
    //2.- Pedir al usuario el tamaño de la sopa
    int arraySize;
    while((arraySize=readInt("Dame tamaño de la sopa: "))<=6) { //Obligo al usuario que indique un tamaño mayor o igual a 6
        System.out.printf(" El tamaño debe ser mayor a 6.\n\n");
    }
    char sopa[][]=new char[arraySize][arraySize]; //Creo un array de tipo char con el tamaño indicado NxN
    for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++) {
        Arrays.fill(sopa[i],'º');//Uso este metodo que te rellena todo del caracter indicado
    }
    for(int i=0; i<palabras.length;i++) {
        int f,c;
        f=Integer.parseInt(palabras[i][1]);//Obtiene la fila
        c=Integer.parseInt(palabras[i][2]);//Obtiene la columna
        switch(Integer.parseInt(palabras[i][3])) {
            case 1:
                /*
                 * Arriba izquierda -->
                 *  F--
                 *  C--
                 */
                if(espacio(palabras,sopa,f,c,i)) {
                    for(int x=0;x<palabras[i][0].length();x++,f--,c--) {
                        sopa[f][c]=palabras[i][0].charAt(x);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.printf("La palabra %s no se ha añadido.\n",palabras[i][0]);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                /*
                 * Arriba Derecha -->
                 * F--
                 * C++
                 */
                if(espacio(palabras,sopa,f,c,i)) {
                    for(int x=0;x<palabras[i][0].length();x++,f--,c++) {
                        sopa[f][c]=palabras[i][0].charAt(x);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.printf("La palabra %s no se ha añadido.\n",palabras[i][0]);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                /*
                 * Abajo Izquierda
                 * F++
                 * C--
                 */
                if(espacio(palabras,sopa,f,c,i)) {
                    for(int x=0;x<palabras[i][0].length();x++,f++,c--) {
                        sopa[f][c]=palabras[i][0].charAt(x);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.printf("La palabra %s no se ha añadido.\n",palabras[i][0]);
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                /*
                 * Abajo Derecha
                 * F++
                 * C++
                 */
                if(espacio(palabras,sopa,f,c,i)) {
                    for(int x=0;x<palabras[i][0].length();x++,f++,c++) {
                        sopa[f][c]=palabras[i][0].charAt(x);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.printf("La palabra %s no se ha añadido.\n",palabras[i][0]);
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                /*
                 * Arriba
                 * F--
                 * c=
                 *
                 */
                //Filas no puede ser menor tamaño de palabra para comprobar si cabe
                //Para saber si se cruza comprobar letra por letra
                if(espacio(palabras,sopa,f,c,i)) {
                    for(int x=0;x<palabras[i][0].length();x++,f--) {
                        sopa[f][c]=palabras[i][0].charAt(x);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.printf("La palabra %s no se ha añadido.\n",palabras[i][0]);
                }


                break;
            case 6:
                /*
                 * F++
                 * c=
                 */
                if(espacio(palabras,sopa,f,c,i)) {
                    for(int x=0;x<palabras[i][0].length();x++,f++) {
                        sopa[f][c]=palabras[i][0].charAt(x);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.printf("La palabra %s no se ha añadido.\n",palabras[i][0]);
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                /*
                 * Derecha
                 * F=
                 * C++
                 */
                if(espacio(palabras,sopa,f,c,i)) {
                    for(int x=0;x<palabras[i][0].length();x++,c++) {
                        sopa[f][c]=palabras[i][0].charAt(x);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.printf("La palabra %s no se ha añadido.\n",palabras[i][0]);
                }
                break;
            default:
                /*
                 * F=
                 * C--
                 */
                if(espacio(palabras,sopa,f,c,i)) {
                    for(int x=0;x<palabras[i][0].length();x++,c--) {
                        sopa[f][c]=palabras[i][0].charAt(x);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.printf("La palabra %s no se ha añadido.\n",palabras[i][0]);
                }
        }
    }
    return sopa;
}
public static boolean espacio(String[][]palabras,char[][] sopa,int fila, int columna,int turno) {
    boolean espacio= false,coincide=true,resultado=false;
    int operacion;
    switch(Integer.parseInt(palabras[turno][3])) {
        case 1:
            /*
             * Arriba izquierda -->
             *  F--
             *  C--
             */
            //Si palabra es menor que fila o el resultado de la columna-Palabra es mayor o igual a 0 habra espacio
            if(palabras[turno][0].length()-1<=fila && (columna-palabras[turno][0].length()-1)>=0) {
                espacio=true;
            }
            //Comprueba si coincide con una letra de la sopa
            for(int i=0; i<palabras[turno][0].length();i++,fila--,columna--){
                if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) {
                    coincide=false;
                }
            }
            if(espacio&&coincide) { //Si hay espacio y coinciden todas las letras entoces devuleve true
                resultado=true;
            }
            else { //Si no, no se podra meter
                resultado=false;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            /*
             * Arriba Derecha -->
             * F--
             * C++
             */
            //Si la palabra es mennor que la fila y menor que el tamaño de la matriz menos la columna
            if(palabras[turno][0].length()-1<=fila && palabras[turno][0].length()-1<=(sopa.length-columna)) {
                espacio=true;
            }
            //Comprueba si coincide con una letra de la sopa
            for(int i=0; i<palabras[turno][0].length();i++,fila--,columna++){
                if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) {
                    coincide=false;
                }
            }
            if(espacio&&coincide) { //Si hay espacio y coinciden todas las letras entoces devuleve true
                resultado=true;
            }
            else { //Si no, no se podra meter
                resultado=false;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            /*
             * Abajo Izquierda
             * F++
             * C--
             */
            //Si la columna es mayor o igual que la palabra y si el resultado de: (tamaño matriz-fila)+1 
            if(palabras[turno][0].length()-1<=columna && palabras[turno][0].length()-1>=(sopa.length-fila+1)) {
                espacio=true;
            }
            //Comprueba si coincide con una letra de la sopa
            for(int i=0; i<palabras[turno][0].length();i++,fila++,columna--){
                if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) {
                    coincide=false;
                }
            }
            if(espacio&&coincide) { //Si hay espacio y coinciden todas las letras entoces devuleve true
                resultado=true;
            }
            else { //Si no, no se podra meter
                resultado=false;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            /*
             * Abajo Derecha
             * F++
             * C++
             */
            //Si la palabra es mas grande que el tamaño de la matriz hay espacio
            if(palabras[turno][0].length()-1<=sopa.length) {
                espacio=true;
            }
            //Comprueba si coincide con una letra de la sopa
            for(int i=0; i<palabras[turno][0].length();i++,fila++,columna++){
                if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) {
                    coincide=false;
                }
            }
            if(espacio&&coincide) { //Si hay espacio y coinciden todas las letras entoces devuleve true
                resultado=true;
            }
            else { //Si no, no se podra meter
                resultado=false;
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            /*
             * Arriba
             * F--
             * c=
             *
             */
            //Filas no puede ser menor tamaño de palabra para comprobar si cabe
            if(palabras[turno][0].length()-1<=fila) {
                espacio=true;
            }
            //Comprueba si coincide con una letra de la sopa
            for(int i=0; i<palabras[turno][0].length();i++,fila--){
                if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) {
                    coincide=false;
                }
            }
            if(espacio&&coincide) { //Si hay espacio y coinciden todas las letras entoces devuleve true
                resultado=true;
            }
            else { //Si no, no se podra meter
                resultado=false;
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            /*
             * Abajo
             * F++
             * c=
             */
            //Si la palabra es mas pequeña que el tamaño de la matriz hay espacio
            if(palabras[turno][0].length()-1<=sopa.length) {
                espacio=true;
            }
            //Comprueba si coincide con una letra de la sopa
            for(int i=0; i<palabras[turno][0].length();i++,fila++){
                if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) {
                    coincide=false;
                }
            }
            if(espacio&&coincide) { //Si hay espacio y coinciden todas las letras entoces devuleve true
                resultado=true;
            }
            else { //Si no, no se podra meter
                resultado=false;
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            /*
             * Derecha
             * F=
             * C++
             */
            //Si la resta de el tamaño de la sopa y la columna indicada es mayor o igual a la palabra hay espacio

            if(palabras[turno][0].length()<=sopa.length-columna+1) {
                espacio=true;
            }
            //Comprueba si coincide con una letra de la sopa
            for(int i=0; i<palabras[turno][0].length();i++,columna++){
                if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) {
                    coincide=false;
                }
            }
            if(espacio&&coincide) { //Si hay espacio y coinciden todas las letras entoces devuleve true
                resultado=true;
            }
            else { //Si no, no se podra meter
                resultado=false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            /*
             * F=
             * C--
             */
            //Si la palabra menos la columna es mayor o igual a 0
            if((palabras[turno][0].length()-1)-columna>=0) {
                espacio=true;
            }
            //Comprueba si coincide con una letra de la sopa
            for(int i=0; i<palabras[turno][0].length();i++,columna--){
                if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) {
                    coincide=false;
                }
            }
            if(espacio&&coincide) { //Si hay espacio y coinciden todas las letras entoces devuelve true
                resultado=true;
            }
            else { //Si no, no se podra meter
                resultado=false;
            }
            break;
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

y este es el fallo:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 16 out of bounds for length 16
at sopaLetras.CreacionSopa.espacio(CreacionSopa.java:373)
at sopaLetras.CreacionSopa.crearSopaLetras(CreacionSopa.java:191)
at sopaLetras.Menu.main(Menu.java:27)
```

el codigo lo ejecuto desde aqui:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] prueba = null;
    String[][] prueba0;
    boolean exit=false;
    do {
        //1.- Mostrar un menu con 4 opciones:
        System.out.print("Elige una opcion:\n\t 1) Crear sopa de letras\n\t 2) Mostrar sopa de letras\n\t 3) Jugar a la sopa de letras\n\t 4) Salir\n");
        switch(between(BetweenOptions.BOTHIN,1,4)) {
            // 1.1.- Opcion 1: Crear sopa de letras
            case 1:
                prueba0=peticionPalabras();
                prueba=crearSopaLetras(prueba0);
                break;
            case 2:
                for(int i=0;i<prueba.length;i++) {
                    for(int x=0;x<prueba[i].length;x++) {
                        System.out.printf("%s ",prueba[i][x]);
                    } 
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
                break;
            case 3:

                break;
            default:
                exit=true;
        }
    }while(!exit);
}
```

Algunas funciones son importada de una clase teclado.

Comment: Puedes mostrar la función crearSopaLetras?

Comment: ¿Que hay en la línea 373 de CreacionSopa?

Comment: El error ocurre en el método que no nos muestras

Comment: Siento se copio dos veces el mismo codigo a continuación lo edito

Comment: @JDev La linea es la siguiente:  `if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) { ` que se encuentra en la funcion espacios,  `case 7: `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logre arreglarlo de la siguiente manera espero que os sea de ayuda:

```
public static boolean espacio(String[][]palabras,char[][] sopa,int fila, int columna,int turno) {
    boolean espacio= false,coincide=true,resultado=false;
    int numLetras=palabras[turno][0].length();
    boolean arriba=fila-numLetras>=-1,izquierda=columna-numLetras>=-1,abajo=fila+numLetras<=sopa.length,derecha=columna+numLetras<=sopa.length;
    switch(Integer.parseInt(palabras[turno][3])) {
        case 1:
            /*
             * Arriba izquierda -->
             *  F--
             *  C--
             */
            //Si palabra es menor que fila o el resultado de la columna-Palabra es mayor o igual a 0 habra espacio
            if(arriba&& izquierda) {
                espacio=true;
            }
            //Comprueba si coincide con una letra de la sopa
            for(int i=0; i<palabras[turno][0].length()&& espacio;i++,fila--,columna--){
                if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) {
                    coincide=false;
                }
            }
            if(espacio&&coincide) { //Si hay espacio y coinciden todas las letras entoces devuleve true
                resultado=true;
            }
            else { //Si no, no se podra meter
                resultado=false;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            /*
             * Arriba Derecha -->
             * F--
             * C++
             */
            //Si la palabra es mennor que la fila y menor que el tamaño de la matriz menos la columna
            if(arriba&& derecha) {
                espacio=true;
            }
            //Comprueba si coincide con una letra de la sopa
            for(int i=0; i<palabras[turno][0].length()&&espacio;i++,fila--,columna++){
                if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) {
                    coincide=false;
                }
            }
            if(espacio&&coincide) { //Si hay espacio y coinciden todas las letras entoces devuleve true
                resultado=true;
            }
            else { //Si no, no se podra meter
                resultado=false;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            /*
             * Abajo Izquierda
             * F++
             * C--
             */
            //Si la columna es mayor o igual que la palabra y si el resultado de: (tamaño matriz-fila)+1 
            if(abajo && izquierda) {
                espacio=true;
            }
            //Comprueba si coincide con una letra de la sopa
            for(int i=0; i<palabras[turno][0].length()&&espacio;i++,fila++,columna--){
                if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) {
                    coincide=false;
                }
            }
            if(espacio&&coincide) { //Si hay espacio y coinciden todas las letras entoces devuleve true
                resultado=true;
            }
            else { //Si no, no se podra meter
                resultado=false;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            /*
             * Abajo Derecha
             * F++
             * C++
             */
            //Si la palabra es mas grande que el tamaño de la matriz hay espacio
            if(abajo&&derecha) {
                espacio=true;
            }
            //Comprueba si coincide con una letra de la sopa
            for(int i=0; i<palabras[turno][0].length()&&espacio;i++,fila++,columna++){
                if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) {
                    coincide=false;
                }
            }
            if(espacio&&coincide) { //Si hay espacio y coinciden todas las letras entoces devuleve true
                resultado=true;
            }
            else { //Si no, no se podra meter
                resultado=false;
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            /*
             * Arriba
             * F--
             * c=
             *
             */
            //Filas no puede ser menor tamaño de palabra para comprobar si cabe
            if(arriba) {
                espacio=true;
            }
            //Comprueba si coincide con una letra de la sopa
            for(int i=0; i<palabras[turno][0].length()&&espacio;i++,fila--){
                if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) {
                    coincide=false;
                }
            }
            if(espacio&&coincide) { //Si hay espacio y coinciden todas las letras entoces devuleve true
                resultado=true;
            }
            else { //Si no, no se podra meter
                resultado=false;
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            /*
             * Abajo
             * F++
             * c=
             */
            //Si la palabra es mas pequeña que el tamaño de la matriz hay espacio
            if(abajo) {
                espacio=true;
            }
            //Comprueba si coincide con una letra de la sopa
            for(int i=0; i<palabras[turno][0].length()&&espacio;i++,fila++){
                if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) {
                    coincide=false;
                }
            }
            if(espacio&&coincide) { //Si hay espacio y coinciden todas las letras entoces devuleve true
                resultado=true;
            }
            else { //Si no, no se podra meter
                resultado=false;
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            /*
             * Derecha
             * F=
             * C++
             */
            //Si la resta de el tamaño de la sopa y la columna indicada es mayor o igual a la palabra hay espacio

            if(derecha) {
                espacio=true;
            }
            //Comprueba si coincide con una letra de la sopa
            for(int i=0; i<palabras[turno][0].length()&&espacio;i++,columna++){
                if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) {
                    coincide=false;
                }
            }
            if(espacio&&coincide) { //Si hay espacio y coinciden todas las letras entoces devuleve true
                resultado=true;
            }
            else { //Si no, no se podra meter
                resultado=false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            /*
             * F=
             * C--
             */
            //Si la palabra menos la columna es mayor o igual a 0
            if(izquierda) {
                espacio=true;
            }
            //Comprueba si coincide con una letra de la sopa
            for(int i=0; i<palabras[turno][0].length()&&espacio;i++,columna--){
                if(sopa[fila][columna]!='º'&& sopa[fila][columna]!=palabras[turno][0].charAt(i)) {
                    coincide=false;
                }
            }
            if(espacio&&coincide) { //Si hay espacio y coinciden todas las letras entoces devuelve true
                resultado=true;
            }
            else { //Si no, no se podra meter
                resultado=false;
            }
            break;
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El error se encuentra en tu comprobación de espacio:

```
if(palabras[turno][0].length()<=sopa.length-columna+1) {
                espacio=true;
}
```

Debería ser:

```
if(palabras[turno][0].length()<=sopa.length-columna) {
                    espacio=true; }
```

Hice una simple prueba de escritorio con tamaño de sopa de letra 8 y columna 2 y según tu comprobación podría tener palabras menores o iguales a 7 letras lo cual no es correcto.

Comment: Te agradezco tu ayuda pero me sigue dando este error comentado anteriormente, pruebe la palabra Hlc fila 15, columna 15, derecha hay salta la excepcion